# Render the Guttenberg editor front-end of website WordPress 5

Tags: wordpress

By using the [`wp_editor()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_editor) function we can render the classic editor on the front-end of a website.

But how can I render the *Guttenberg* editor instead of the *Classic Editor*?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know the only avaiable option is ["Frontenberg"](https://github.com/tomjn/Frontenberg)
it CAN render gutenberg but it should NOT be used as a frontend editor

from Frontendberg's readme:

> Is it Safe in Production?
>   Probably not, it was built specifically for https://frontenberg.tomjn.com, not as a general purpose block editor component.
>
> Can I Use it On a Client Site?
>   I strongly recommend against it